# Closed path (for filling) with different strokes

Tags: wpf

I'd like to create a closed `Path`, but with different strokes for the elements that make up the path.

So, for instance. I'd like to create a shape from three bezier curves, this shape is closed, so that I can give it a fill. But each of the three bezier curves should have it's own stroke thickness or stroke color.

As far as I know... since I'd like to give it a fill, I have to use one `Path` object, but the stroke and the stroke thickness can only be set on this very same `Path` object, so it is used for all three bezier curves.

`CombinedGeometry` doesn't work either, since it is used inside one single `Path` object.

So, is there something like a `PathCollection` object, that I can use in XAML?

Comment: maybe add a picture of what you are trying to achive and we can figure out a way to help you! Or are you planning on something dynamically generated?

Comment: I plan to create an irregular shaped button. But since I couldn't find a decent way to automatically size this irregular shaped button to the sitze of it's content I thought about putting a bezier path to the left and the right of the rectangle containing the content. And to be able to give my button (combined beziers and rectangle) a background and a border I need to be able to fill the shape (background) and to giveparts of the shape a stroke and a stroke thickness.

Comment: I probably go with a closed shape for filling and an identical shape for the stroke/stroke thickness.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a single Path, you have to create a separate Path for each element.

LinearGradientBrush, as an example, won't work because it declares a starting and ending X/Y coordinate. If your shape is a rectangle then there are some tricks you can do to exploit this which you can use for animated marquees etc but it doesn't work for arbitrary paths.